# Load Iframe only once in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, next.js

In a NextJS Single Page application I have a page with an Iframe which loads application X inside it.

Since application X is quite big and takes time to load, I would like to load this Iframe just once when the user visits the page and then if the user navigates to another page of the application and then comes back to the page with the Iframe then it just displays the loaded Iframe with application X.

The page with the Iframe receives an ID as URL parameter that I intent to pass to the Iframe trough message. There will be a communication channel between the Iframe and React.

Is there a way to just load the Iframe once?
Maybe force React to never unload the component that contains the Iframe?

Comment: If your site works such that "navigate to another page" means to reload the browser tab completely, then there's not much that React or Next can do about it; everything in the former DOM is thrown out. Now, if you've got a Single-Page Application, then you can keep things around, but the user reloading the page deliberately will also start with a completely fresh `window`.

Comment: It's a Single Page Application.

Comment: Yea in my last SPA I would have just hidden the iframe and kept it somewhere in the DOM, so that I could later move it back. (I wasn't using React or Next.)